# Set NDK version for react-native module

Tags: android, react-native, sdk, android-ndk

I'm trying to setup [react-native skia](https://github.com/Shopify/react-native-skia) library into project.

IOS working perfectly but not Android.

In the documentation, it's wrote :

> Currently, you will need Android NDK to be installed. If you have Android Studio installed, make sure $ANDROID_NDK is available. ANDROID_NDK=/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle for instance.

I got files into this folder, so I'm supposed android NDK is installed :

[ndk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESo6d.png)

But what is $ANDROID_NDK ? A variable into Android Studio ? Mine was :

[variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23sRS.png)

Then, it's wrote in the documentation :

> And them the Modules section. click on shopify_react-native-skia and select NDK version with dropdown, and click on apply.

but I don't have shopify_react-native-skia module :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJwka.png)

Btw, in this part of settings, I have nothing on ndk field, and it is not enable to set something :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YfB2.png)

(I cant' post images for now because I need 10 reputations)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have this exact problem now